# When is it appropriate to use a directive scope without its own controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

My understanding is that the directives should be concerned mostly with DOM interaction and templating. Setting up the application logic related to the `$scope` is the responsibility of controllers instead.

Yet Angular allows you to create a scope for the directive itself, such as with `{ scope: true }`. If you do this, when are you supposed to initialize like you would in your controller constructor -- in the post-link function? That seems like an inappropriate use of the directive, since it's not concerned with the DOM.

When it it appropriate to use an Angular directive scope instead of creating a controller that must be used with that directive instead?

Comment: The local scope of a directive is use for the directive local variables... If you instanciate new component in your directive that need to be binded in a local scope, se the directive scope. If you need to interact with variables outside of the directive, use a controller's scope. Yes, you instanciate it in the post link function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Yet Angular allows you to create a scope for the directive itself,
>   such as with { scope: true }. If you do this, when are you supposed to
>   initialize like you would in your controller constructor -- in the
>   post-link function? That seems like an inappropriate use of the
>   directive, since it's not concerned with the DOM.

A directive can have its own controller, defined by the `controller` option. That controller has the same function as an application controller: to provide behavior for the directive. That said, I think the correct place to initialize the scope is the directive's controller, not its link function.

I think of a directive's controller as the place where you manipulate the scope and of the directive's link function as the place you manipulate the DOM. This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18198592/behavior-of-controller-inside-directives) has some good insights on that matter.

> When is it appropriate to use an Angular directive scope instead of
>   creating a controller that must be used with that directive instead?

Off the top of my head I can think of two scenarios:

- You want your directive to access its parent scope, but don't want it to modify the parent scope's data. In order to do that you need to set the directive to have its own scope, i.e. `scope: true`.
- You want your directive to be reusable. In such a case, the directive shouldn't rely on any parent scope, and should have its own isolate scope, i.e, `scope: {}`.

I've implemented a directive recently and used the controller function for driving its behavior and 
the link function for manipulating the DOM. Perhaps you'd be interested in checking it out. Link [here](https://github.com/mbenford/ngTagsInput).