# Getting an attribute value from a directive's isolated controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

OK, so I have a directive which takes attributes and reads it (and writes it out).

plunker live demo: http://embed.plnkr.co/IkKPLahPc9yqeHWEQUG3/

I think it's because of the controller: ctrl inside **main-directive.js** which has nothing whereas the actual action is happening inside the isolated directive's controller **controller**.

Here is the **main-directive.js**:

```
var app = angular.module('testapp.directive.main', ['main']);

app.directive('myCustomer', function() {

  var controller = ['$scope', function($scope) {

    $scope.dan = { 'name': 'Chad', 'nationality': 'China' };
    // I want the scope.dan object to be read from here.

  }];

  var template = 'Getting attribute value of =getInfo... {{getInfo.name}} from {{getInfo.nationality}}';

  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    controller: controller,
    scope: {
      getInfo: "=info"
    },
    template: template
  };
});

app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  // adding the $scope.dan object here will work
  // but I don't want it here.
});
```

and here's my template for it:

```
'mainview@': {
    controller: 'MainCtrl as mainCtrl',
    template: '<div ng-controller="ctrl"><my-customer info="dan"></my-customer></div>'
}
```

How do I make it so it reads objects from inside the isolated controller inside the directive and NOT from the controller '**ctrl**'?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this post that shows how directives and controllers share $scope.

[Behavior of controller inside directives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18198592/behavior-of-controller-inside-directives)

It looks like you are interested in the custom attributes given to your custom HTML tag. I reformatted your directive and controller and printed out the info attribute that you seem interested in.

```
var app = angular.module('testapp.directive.main', ['main'])
  .directive('myCustomer', function() {

  var template = 'Getting attribute value of =getInfo... {{getInfo.name}} from {{getInfo.nationality}}';

  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    controller: 'ctrl',
    scope: {
      getInfo: "=info"
    },
    template: template
  };
})
.controller('ctrl',['$scope', '$attrs', function($scope, $attrs) {
  $scope.dan = { 'name': 'Chad', 'nationality': 'China' };
  console.log($attrs.info);
}])
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Well.. the whole reason I had the controller isolated inside the directive was for Unit Testing. Having the controller like that... it does not make it reusable, no?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean by reusable. For Instance, you could certainly reuse the controller by referencing `controller: 'ctrl'` from any directive.

Comment: You're right. I was thinking for a controller to be isolated, it had to be INSIDE the directive.

But what is the purpose of having it inside the directive? Anyway, thank you.