# AngularJS: Why and when people declare controller inside custom directives

Tags: angularjs

I have seen a couple of custom directives sample code and saw people declare controller inside custom directives. I am new in angular and that is why just do not understand when and why people declare controller inside custom directives?

### here one usage

```
app.directive('someDirective', function () {
  return {
    scope: {},
    controller: function () {
      this.name = 'Pascal'
    },
    controllerAs: 'ctrl',
    template: '<div>{{ctrl.name}}</div>'
  };
});
```

Code is taken from http://blog.thoughtram.io/angularjs/2015/01/02/exploring-angular-1.3-bindToController.html

Also like to know what is the usage of **bindToController: true,**? what it does and when people use it.

Please help me to understand this with a couple of example and code. I need to understand the importance of declaring controller inside custom directives.

thanks

Comment: Using the controller in a custom directive helps define what controller is being used with the directive element.  The other option would be to create a div wrapper with ng-controller in the directive template but putting it in the directive, personally, is a cleaner and simpler way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand (and what comes from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18198592/behavior-of-controller-inside-directives)), you need that if you want to share particular functionality/data among different directives.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, that's done as a correct practice of using separation of concerns. Even though the code controller body lies inside of the directive definition, you still separate data (which controller is in charge of), and DOM-manipulations, which `link` method is intended to exist for.

If this about why there is controller code at all (and why it's not defined somewhere outside), the I would say "why not?"
If this just a small amount of code which specific particularly for this very directive, it's ok to define it right at a place.

*But from my understanding, such cases might be better served with defining filters, but that all depends on particular app architecture.*